# which of the following are correct among given four statements?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function such that $\int_{0}^\infty f(x)dx $ exist. Then which of the following holds?

1) If $\lim _{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exist, then $\lim _{x \to \infty}f(x)=0$

2) The limit $\lim _{x \to \infty}f(x)$ must exist and zero.

3) In case $f$ is non negative function, $\lim _{x \to \infty} f(x)$ must exist and zero.

4) In case $f$ is differentiable function, $\lim _{x \to \infty}f'(x)$ must exist and is zero.

Comment: Voted to close, but didn't down vote. Any thoughts of your own, examples you've considered, specific places you're stuck, etc.? (Separately, I notice you haven't selected an answer to a single one of the 55 questions you've asked. That seems contrary to the [spirit of the site](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour).)

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: @user290972 You're supposed to mark an answer "right" (green mark in the left block) if it did actually (correctly) answer your question. It helps when someone else later has the same questions and finds yours via search. Also, the site notifies about comment replies only post author and a person whose nickname you write with "@" (as in the beginning of this comment), all other commentators don't know you added something.

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang  i don't know this thing. but now onwards i will take care of this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S(x,k) = \cases{sin(\pi k^2x)^2, x \in [k,k+{1\over k^2}] \\ 0 \, \text{otherwise}}$. Let $f(x) = \sum_k S(x,k)$. $f$ is continuous, non-negative, differentiable. Visually, its graph consists of "spikes" getting thinner while maintaining the same height.

For 1, note that $\int_0^A|f(x)|dx$ would be arbitrarily large otherwise.

Comment: @ Abstraction thanks for letting me know

Comment: @user290972 3) $f$ is non-negative. 1) As I said, suppose the contrary - say that $\exists \lim_{x \to +\infty}f(x)=2$, then there is $x_0 : x>x_0 \implies f(x)>1$ and derive contradiction with initial statement $\exists \int_0^{+\infty}f(x)dx$.

Comment: @ Abstraction Can you please show the graph?

Comment: @user290972 in WolframAlpha, `plot sin(π2^2x)^2 from x=2 to (2+1/2^2)` and then it's $0$ up to $x=3$, then `plot sin(π3^2x)^2 from x=3 to (3+1/3^2)` and then it's $0$ up to $x=4$ and so forth.

Comment: @ Abstraction Thanks a lot. any counterexample for 2)?

Comment: @user290972 This is it. Should be fairly obvious that such a function has no limit as $x \to +\infty$ (since it equals $1$ for arbitrarily large $x$).

Comment: @ Abstraction Sir i am talking about 2) That limit must exist.. any counterexample

Comment: @user290972 Then I'm not sure I understand. Function $f$ from the answer is "a continuous function such that $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ exists". Yet, it doesn't satisfy **2)** (there is no limit), **3)** (it's non-negative and there still is no limit) or **4)** (it's differentiable but its derivative also has no limit).

Comment: @ Abstraction  I able to prove 1) and  for statement 4) you give a counter example. Now 3) is also explained by you, Now i am looking for any function which contradict the statement 2)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41294/discussion-between-abstraction-and-user290972).